# How to add values based on the output of xrange()?

Tags: python

I am not sure if I worded the title correctly, but what I am trying to do is find the sum of the values that xrange() is being passed.

**Ideally,** it would look something like this: (note, this is not working code)

```
mofthree = xrange(2, 1000, 3)
moffive = xrange(4, 996, 5)

print mofthree + moffive
```

But of course, you can't add two functions together.  I would also be okay with doing something like adding all the values in, for example, `mofthree` together, storing the result in a new variable, and then doing the same for `moffive` and adding the two new variables together.

However, I simply do not know a way to go about adding these values together either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [sum()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> sum(xrange(2, 1000, 3))
166500
>>> sum(xrange(4, 996, 5))
99301
```

Answer (score 6):

```
mofthree = xrange(2, 1000, 3)
moffive = xrange(4, 996, 5)

print sum(mofthree) + sum(moffive)
```

Or use itertools and [`chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain
mofthree = xrange(2, 1000, 3)
moffive = xrange(4, 996, 5)

print sum(chain(moffive, mofthree))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running through every item in the range and adding them, you can use the formula for the sum of an arithmetic series, like so:

```
def sum_range(*args):
    # parse the arguments, using the same positional notation as range()
    lo,hi,step = [
        lambda args: (0,       args[0], 1),
        lambda args: (args[0], args[1], 1),
        lambda args: args
    ][len(args)-1](args)

    # make sure we handle negative steps properly
    flip_sign = (step < 0)
    if flip_sign:
        lo,hi,step = -lo,-hi,-step

    # and do the actual calculation
    items = (hi - lo + step - 1) // step
    if items <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        total = (2*lo + (items-1)*step) * items // 2
        return -total if flip_sign else total
```

then you can use it like

```
print sum_range(2, 1000, 3) + sum_range(4, 996, 5)
```

For interest, I ran a comparative timing against Frédéric Hamidi's answer:

[image: graph of algorithm runtime]

where the x axis is the number of items in the range, y axis is runtime, my algorithm is in green and his is in blue. As expected, his algorithm's runtime is proportional to the number of items and mine is constant, with the point of intersection at about 75 items.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! But I am only a beginner Python programmer, if that, so there's a bit in there that's much beyond my knowledge. But thanks again.